# How can I customize Hudson's build failure email?

Tags: hudson

I want to add some custom text to the build failure email in Hudson.  It looks like you can only customize the successful build message?  Is this correct, or else how do you do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [Email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) plugin. Also, I suggest you use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org), not Hudson.